# Обработка 2-ух и более Spinner в одном Activity

Tags: android, android-spinner

На одном `Activity` есть 4 `Spinner`'a. Как написать один метод для них всех, который будет возвращать выбранные значения?

Код такой:

```
private void setSpinner(){
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
            R.array.the_number_day, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    spinnerIntervalMount.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinnerIntervalMount.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String[] tmp = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.the_number_day);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
```

По сути код одинаков для всех `Spinner`, за исключением массива данных - `R.array...`

После гугления, пришёл к такому решению, оцените пожалуйста этот код:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    setSpinner(spinner, R.array.catlist);
}

private void setSpinner(Spinner spinner, final int resourse){
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemSelected, int selectedItemPosition, long selectedId) {

            String[] choose = getResources().getStringArray(resourse);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Ваш выбор: " + choose[selectedItemPosition], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Смущает, что отсутствует адаптер.

Comment: передавайте в метод сам спиннер, у которого надо взять значение, а в методе - используйте спиннер из параметра